# How to (correctly) embed a Facebook video?

Tags: facebook, embed, videos

I'm trying to embed a Facebook video in my site using the snippets generated by the [Facebook Embedded videos page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/embedded-video-player).

Having done so, I add this function to a custom, site specific plugin so as to load the FB javascript API:

```
add_action('wp_head', 'js_sdk_wp_head');
function js_sdk_wp_head(){
  ?>
  <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script async defer crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v3.3"></script>
  <?php
}
```

I then use the code editor to add the following to the page:

```
<!-- wp:html /-->

<div class="fb-video" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/watch/?v=12345" data-width="500" data-show-text="false">
</div>
```

And when I do so, nothing happens, (apart from a blank line being inserted into the WP post).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked correctly for me, however I used the [wp_enqueue_scripts](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) hook to add the JavaScript.

```
function mytheme_enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_register_script('facebook-video', 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v3.3', '', '');
    wp_enqueue_script('facebook-video');
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mytheme_enqueue_scripts');
```

- Do you see any errors in your browser console or network tab?
- Do you see the JS added to your page if you inspect?

Comment: I've used the above in my plugin. On the Chrome network tab, I can see 2 relevant events. One for the SDK load and another that loads some content (the first frame or two maybe?). In short, it looks like everything is working but the video player just isn't rendering properly.

Comment: What do you see if you right click and view-source on the page? Can you see the fb-video HTML that you added to your post?

Comment: Weirdly, the embedded videos page is now generating a new URL which embeds properly. Will mark this as correct since enqueueing seems more correct. Thanks.